# RabbitMQ management web console doesn't show queues or exchanges

Tags: rabbitmq

I've got rabbitmq 2.8.2 set up with the web management interface running. The Queues and Exchanges show no data.

rabbitmqctl list_queues works and shows my queues.

I've done rabbitmqctl stop_app, start_app.. and also service rabbitmq-server restart.

Any idea how to get the queue & exchange details to populate?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had removed the guest user and created a new user for myself. My new user did not have permission to access the / vhost. Adding that permission fixed my issue.

Comment: This was a life saver... quick and useful :)

Comment: Hey This fixed my initial issue, so thank you! but now it doesn't accurately show the Queues I have, for example when in my console it shows 10 Queues but in the RabbitMQ manager it only shows the Queues I hvae manually created

Answer (score 5):

Rabbitmq users only have permission to view the queues that they created by default. Also if you want the user to have access to the management console you need to grant the right privileges.

To solve this problem I ran:

```
rabbitmqctl set_user_tags <user> management
```

There is more information on setting up the correct permissions for accessing the management console on RabbitMQs website: https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html