# RabbitMQ management returns 500 when trying to list queues

Tags: rabbitmq

I've just installed Erlang 19.0, then Rabbitmq Server 3.6.3. OS - Windows 10. Then I installed rabbitmq_management plugin, then I started rabbitmq-server. I can successfully login into management console. The problem is when I go to Queues I get as error:

> Got response code 500 with body {"error":"JSON encode error:
>   {bad_term,#{error_logger => true,kill => true,size =>
>   0}}","reason":"While encoding: \n[{total_count,1},\n {item_count,1},\n
>   {filtered_count,1},\n {page,1},\n {page_size,100},\n {page_count,1},\n
>   {items,\n [[{memory,22048},\n {reductions,6633},\n
>   {reductions_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {messages,0},\n
>   {messages_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n {messages_ready,0},\n
>   {messages_ready_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n
>   {messages_unacknowledged,0},\n
>   {messages_unacknowledged_details,[{rate,0.0}]},\n
>   {idle_since,<<\"2016-07-08 20:55:04\">>},\n
>   {consumer_utilisation,''},\n {policy,''},\n
>   {exclusive_consumer_tag,''},\n {consumers,1},\n
>   {recoverable_slaves,''},\n {state,running},\n {reductions,6633},\n
>   {garbage_collection,\n [{max_heap_size,#{error_logger => true,kill =>
>   true,size => 0}},\n {min_bin_vheap_size,46422},\n
>   {min_heap_size,233},\n {fullsweep_after,65535},\n {minor_gcs,3}]},\n
>   {messages_ram,0},\n {messages_ready_ram,0},\n
>   {messages_unacknowledged_ram,0},\n {messages_persistent,0},\n
>   {message_bytes,0},\n {message_bytes_ready,0},\n
>   {message_bytes_unacknowledged,0},\n {message_bytes_ram,0},\n
>   {message_bytes_persistent,0},\n {head_message_timestamp,''},\n
>   {disk_reads,0},\n {disk_writes,0},\n {backing_queue_status,\n
>   {struct,\n [{mode,default},\n {q1,0},\n {q2,0},\n
>   {delta,[delta,undefined,0,undefined]},\n {q3,0},\n {q4,0},\n
>   {len,0},\n {target_ram_count,infinity},\n {next_seq_id,0},\n
>   {avg_ingress_rate,0.0},\n {avg_egress_rate,0.0},\n
>   {avg_ack_ingress_rate,0.0},\n {avg_ack_egress_rate,0.0}]}},\n
>   {node,'rabbit@DESKTOP-330SD1I'},\n {arguments,{struct,[]}},\n
>   {exclusive,false},\n {auto_delete,false},\n {durable,true},\n
>   {vhost,<<\"/\">>},\n {name,<<\"queue1\">>}]]}]"}

If I remove from myself a privilegy to access "/" virtual host error disappears, but no queues are shown, which I suppose is wrong, because I have a running application which sends and reveives messages.

[Here is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939545/rabbitmq-management-web-console-doesnt-show-queues-or-exchanges) the closest question to my, but those solution doesn't help.

P.S. I don't even hope somebody help me, I just wanted to post this question so at least this error can be googled.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

there are some known issues with Erlang 19, [discussed in the RMQ Google Group, here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/rabbitmq-users/Erlang$2019.0/rabbitmq-users/pa1UtLbbvOE/EZVG_LlkBwAJ).

> In other words, 3.6.3 effectively isn't Erlang 19.0-compatible:

you'll need to install a prior version of Erlang, until RMQ can be re-built to support the changes in Erlang 19

Comment: This works! Can't believe there is no information about that on the rabbitmq website.

Comment: erlang 19 has only been out for a few weeks. sometimes it takes a while for information to move from testing to the site.

Comment: For those of you who are using Archlinux I recommend: wget 
https://archive.archlinux.org/repos/2015/11/01/community/os/x86_64/erlang-18.1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz and pacman -U erlang-18.1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz . This package works great :)

Answer (score 3):

I've installed Erlang OTP 18.0 and RabbitMq 3.6.3 management console started to work fine. Before I tried to use OTP 19.0 and I got errors during browsing web-console.

Answer (score 2):

I upgraded RabbitMQ to **3.6.5** and the error got resolved. It is now working with Erlang **19.0**.